# Spark using cassandra partitioning with Java API

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, partitioning, connector

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE attribute (
    pid text,
    partner_id int,
    key int,
    value int,
    PRIMARY KEY (pid, partner_id, key)
)
```

I am trying to key my RDD by 'pid' which is the partition key.
According to the documentation I can do that by calling the keyBy method like this:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Attribute> attrRdd =
    javaFunctions(context).cassandraTable(ks, cf, mapRowTo(Attribute.class))
    .select(column("pid"), column("partner_id"), column("key"), column("value"))
    .keyBy(new Function<Attribute, String>() {
        @Override
        public String call(Attribute attr) throws Exception {
            return attr.getPid();
        }
    });
```

However, this doesn't create the cassandra partitioner. The only time I get the cassandra partitioner is when I key by all primary key columns like so:

```
JavaPairRDD<AttributePK, Attribute> attrRdd =
    javaFunctions(context).cassandraTable(ks, cf, mapRowTo(Attribute.class))
    .select(column("pid"), column("partner_id"), column("key"), column("value"))
    .keyBy(JavaApiHelper.getClassTag(AttributePK.class),
        mapRowTo(AttributePK.class), mapToRow(AttributePK.class), column("pid"));
```

AttributePK has all PK column as members:

```
public class AttributePK {
    protected String pid;
    protected int partner_id;
    protected int key;
    ...
}
```

This is not good for me because eventually I want to group all entries by 'pid' without shuffling.

Does someone know why I fail to key by only the partition key column as described in the documentation?

Thanks,

Shai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two different api's here. The first example passes a function and the second passes columns. When you pass a function there is no way for the api to know what the columns in the Key will be so it can't build the partitioner. Try using the "KeyBy" function with the column api.

Additionally you probably don't need to do this specifically as the `spanBy` api should let you do groupByKey/reduceByKey operations for free on the Partition key.

Comment: Thanks RussS, you are totally right!! However, I do find the explanations and examples in the "How to take advantage of Cassandra Partitioning in Spark" section in the docs confusing. It specifically talks about calling keyBy to generate the cassandra partitioner, and not mentioning the spanBy option. The spanByKey function is mentioned but as a way to do it in older versions.